# can not finding the css,js and images

Tags: codeigniter

i am  very new in codeigniter.I have a static web page.i just want to convert it into dynamic web page.First of all i pasted all the files in the `view` folder of the MVC of the codeigniter.Here i have `css`, `javascript` and `images` folder and my php files.

I have created a controller like this..

```
<?php
  class Saffron extends CI_Controller
{
 function index()
     {
       $this->load->view('home');
     }   

}
?>
```

and my `home.php` page  is just like this..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Home</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
media="screen" href="<?= base_url() ?>application/views/css/reset.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
media="screen" href="<?= base_url() ?>application/views/css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
media="screen" href="<?= base_url() ?>application/views/css/slider.css">

<script src="<? echo base_url(); ?>application/views/js/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
<script src="<? echo base_url(); ?>application/views/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="<? echo base_url(); ?>application/views/js/tms-0.4.1.js"></script>
<script src="<? echo base_url(); ?>application/views/js/vpb_script.js"></script>
<script src="<? echo base_url(); ?>application/views/js/pop.js"></script>

<!--start popup window ref-->
<link href="application/views/css/colorbox.css" 
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="<? echo base_url(); ?>application/views/js/jquery_002.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".image_show").colorbox({rel:'image_show', transition:"fade"});

    });
</script>
<!--end popup window ref-->


<!--[if lt IE 8]>
   <div style=' clear: both; text-align:center; position: relative;'>
     <a href="http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/
internet-explorer/products/ie/home?ocid=ie6_countdown_bannercode">
       <img src="http://storage.ie6countdown.com/assets/100/
images/banners/warning_bar_0000_us.jpg" border="0" height="42" 
width="820" alt="You are using an outdated browser. For a faster, 
safer browsing experience, upgrade for free today." />
    </a>
  </div>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/html5.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/ie.css">
<![endif]-->
</head>





<body>
<!--<div class="bg-top">-->
<div class="bgr">
<!--==============================Wrapper=================================-->
<div class="wrapper">
<!-----------------------Header --------------------------->
<header>
<div class="head">
    <h1>
        <a href="index.html">
<img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>application/views/images/logo.jpg" alt=""></a>
        <a href="#" class="classname">sign up</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" 
class="classname1" onClick="vpb_show_login_box();">login</a>
    </h1>
</div>



<?php 

   include_once('navigation.php');
   include_once('slider.php');
   include_once('offers.php');
   include_once('invite.php');
   include_once('testimonial.php');
   include_once('special_item.php');
   include_once('footer.php');
   include_once('popup.php');
   ?>
```

Now what the mistake there...or anyelse that i can't recognizing??...please hlp me.
Thanks in Advance...

Comment: you are not supposed to use "include()" anywhere in your code except including config files etc. codeigniter is MVC try dig into it and load views insted including them. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to put echo on several places.

I can show you my solution for putting files in header. First I made a folder in the root and named it **public**, and in that folder I created folders for needed documents (css, img, js...). In **constants.php** I made this:

```
$root = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$root .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
define('ABSOLUTE_PATH', str_replace('system/','', BASEPATH));
define('BASE', $root);
define('CSS', BASE . 'public/css/');
define('JS', BASE . 'public/js/');
define('IMG', BASE . 'public/img/');
```

So in the header you can do this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo  CSS ?>reset.css">
```

This is a easy way to maintain and update your files.

Answer (score 1):

Sasha gave a good solution, but to answer your question: all your CSS, images, JS should not reside inside the application folder, but in a folder on the same level as application. `assets`is a common name for such a folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. in your config file, define the base_url() ex, base_url() = 'yoursite';
2. in root directory create a folder and name it resource and put all your css, js, img folders inside
3. in your html/php view file (ex. application/views/test.php) along with html code put these php codes, example

NOTE: don't worry about echoing the base_url in every js or css file that you link because base has been already defined.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Home</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<base href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="resource/css/reset.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="resource/css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="resource/css/slider.css">

<script src="resource/js/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
<script src="resource/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="resource/js/tms-0.4.1.js"></script>
<script src="resource/js/vpb_script.js"></script>
<script src="resource/js/pop.js"></script>
```